# Outlook Search in Mail function (ctrl-f equivalent)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, find-and-replace

I need to find a certain keyword in an outlook email. Typically you would use ctrl-f in a situation like this, but annoyingly outlook has never supported ctrl-f searching

When I search the internet, I find websites that tell me ctrl-e or ctrl-shift-f should work. It doesnt (although I think ctrl-e might have worked in the past), it just redirects me to the "search all mails" bar:

[image]

Another keyboard shortcut that some websites suggest is ctrl-shift-f, that doesnt work either. It gives me this huge popout that searches all mails, not just the one I'm looking at.

[image]

This is what my outlook looks like. It just says "Outlook" no clarifiers. It might be a part of office365 stuff? But I'm not sure.

[image]

Another suggestion I came across on websites said.. literally just F4? It does absolutely nothing on my machine.

How do I accomplish the elusive task of searching for a word in the body of an email in outlook, short of copy pasting the whole mail to notepad and using ctrl-f in notepad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to search an Outlook folder with Ctrl-F?](https://superuser.com/questions/258015/is-it-possible-to-search-an-outlook-folder-with-ctrl-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a word in the body of an email in outlook, the shortcut F4 is valid, but **it is only valid when you double-click to open the message**.

Please try to open the email instead of previewing it in the reading pane and press F4 , the below window will be shown. Then you can easily search the words you need.

[image]

Comment: I gotta double click the email before I can search the contents? Man... They dont teach you this in school...